# Advanced search with MongoDb Find

Tags: php, mongodb

Does this expression's analog exist in MongoDb:
PHP analog:

```
if( (isset(field) AND field>10000) OR !isset(field) ){}
```

Comment: Its unclear. Show what you want to achieve.

Comment: [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). And there is nothing "advanced" here at all. Reading the documentation might be a wise idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you want:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[
    {field:{$gt:10000}},
    {field:{$exists:false}}
 ]})
```